# Insert pure HTML in Mysql and retrieving HTML to show on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Got a problem regarding my application. It's a form maker, which you can build your own form, and use that form later on. The generated HTML code of the form which is created by the form builder, I insert that in the MySQL database.

But if I want to get the form out of the DB, the HTML isn't shown correctly. Probably due to quotation marks. Here is some data:

```
&lt;form class="form-horizontal" &gt;<fieldset>
```

This is part of the data which gets inserted into the DB. You can see that it converts some characters, but that doesn't has to be a problem, because it's all HTML code which gets coverted later on.

This is what I get when I insert this data into my page with jQuery and AJAX:

```
&lt;form class="form-horizontal" &gt;<fieldset>&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;<legend>Hubert</legend></fieldset>&lt;/form&gt;
```

THis is a screenshot of the chrome inspector. I insert the data into the div deformvragen.

[image]

Someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

HTMLENTITIES doesnt work, i get this as ouput in my browser, still the quotation marks are still there and thus the form isn't displayed correctly.

```
<div class="deformvragen">&lt;form class="form-horizontal" &gt;
<fieldset>

&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;
<legend>FOrm Numero 4</legend>

&lt;!-- Text input--&gt;
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-0">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    &lt;input id="textinput-0" name="textinput-0" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge"&gt;
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

&lt;!-- Text input--&gt;
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-5">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    &lt;input id="textinput-5" name="textinput-5" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge"&gt;
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

&lt;!-- Text input--&gt;
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-4">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    &lt;input id="textinput-4" name="textinput-4" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge"&gt;
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

&lt;!-- Text input--&gt;
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-3">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    &lt;input id="textinput-3" name="textinput-3" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge"&gt;
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

&lt;!-- Text input--&gt;
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-2">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    &lt;input id="textinput-2" name="textinput-2" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge"&gt;
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

&lt;!-- Text input--&gt;
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-1">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    &lt;input id="textinput-1" name="textinput-1" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge"&gt;
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
&lt;/form&gt;
</div>
```

This is how I do it in my php to mysql file:

```
$convertcontent = htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Than I save it in the MySQL database. Is it possible the encoding of the table isnt right?

Comment: [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: ...and/or `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 1):

`&lt` = Less than = <

`&gt` = Greater than = >

It's not inserting the right way in the database.

As said in the comments, you need [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) before inserting into the database.

Comment: Aha, so the insertion is going wrong, thanks! I thought the insertion was alright. If this is the case after all, I make sure to mark your answer as solution!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using PHP 
Use the function `htmlspecialchars_decode`. 
For more information, here's the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

if you do this on client side, you may use this code:

```
   var htmlEntities = {
      encode : function htmlEscape(str, flag) {
          var htmlToString = String(str)
                  .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                  .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
                  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
          if(flag) {
              // if flag == false don't encode "&" symbole
              htmlToString.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
          }
          return htmlToString;
      },
      decode : function(str) {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
          // strip script/html tags
          str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
          str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
          element.innerHTML = str;
          str = element.textContent;
          element.textContent = '';
        }
        return str;
      }
  };
```

Example how it work from console:

```
htmlEntities.encode('&lt;form class="form-horizontal" &gt;<fieldset>&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;<legend>Hubert</legend></fieldset>&lt;/form&gt', false)

"&lt;form class=&quot;form-horizontal&quot; &gt;&lt;fieldset&gt;&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;&lt;legend&gt;Hubert&lt;/legend&gt;&lt;/fieldset&gt;&lt;/form&gt"

htmlEntities.decode('&lt;form class=&quot;form-horizontal&quot; &gt;&lt;fieldset&gt;&lt;!-- Form Name --&gt;&lt;legend&gt;Hubert&lt;/legend&gt;&lt;/fieldset&gt;&lt;/form&gt');

"<form class="form-horizontal" ><fieldset><!-- Form Name --><legend>Hubert</legend></fieldset></form>"
```

if you use php the best and secure way to use base64_encode( string $data ) and base64_decode(string $data)

```
    <?php
       $str = 'This is an encoded string';
       echo base64_encode($str);
    ?>
```

output: VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

or htmlentities($str)   - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
  <?php
      $str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
      // Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
      echo htmlentities($str);
      // Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
      echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
  ?>
```

Comment: See my edit. HTMLEntities doesnt work. Quotation marks still appear and break the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer eventually myself. The insert into the database went well. I just needed to do a couple of things.

First of all I needed to use PHP to decode the string and then send it to my client applicaiton:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode
```

Then in my client application i used javascript to trim teh result:

```
var html = $.trim(r);
$$('#formvragenhier').html(html);
```

Then I insert it into my application and the HTML is correctly displayed!